# Removing everything after/before the first occurrence of a given string

Tags: string, batch-file, search

I am working on a small utility that is designed to split a file in 2 after the first occurrence of a given delimiter, so that from a single input file, you will get 2 smaller output files.

For example, lets assume you have the input file contents:

```
Alpha
Bravo Charlie
Charlie Echo
```

and the delimiter I am using is `Charlie`, how could I get a pair of output files like:

```
Alpha
Bravo
```

and

```
<blank line>
Charlie Echo
```

I am currently working along the lines of finding the first occurrence of the delimiter string, then performing a substring on the original text twice, using the delimiter string position before split the text, which then gets saved to the output. However, while I have been successful in finding out about how to do substrings, I have not had any success finding out about an `strpos` like function.

So, what can I do to get a strpos like result from an input block of text/file path, or is there another (better?) method of doing what I am trying to do?

N.B. I am unable to use anything beyond Windows Batch Script for this, so while PHP, or Sed, or even Java, its not an option

Comment: Unsure if something like `strpos` exists or can be done with batch, but there's quite definitely another way to achieve what you want. Mind sharing what you've got?

Comment: I don't have anything concrete at the moment, other than a idea of the method I want to go down. Currently, it checks (and creates if they don't exist) the input/output directories, scans the input directory for files, creates two files in the output dir, puts the entire content of the input file in each, and deletes the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution. You can configure the output files in the `_outfile1` and `_outfile2` variables, as well as the split token in `_split`. The input file `input.txt` assumes the content you've stated in your question.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET _outfile1=output1.txt
SET _outfile2=output2.txt
SET _split=Charlie

SET OF=!_outfile1!
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ( input.txt ) DO (
    SET TEST=%%A
    IF "!OF!"=="!_outfile1!" (
        IF "!TEST:%_split%=!"=="%%A" (
            ECHO %%A >> !OF!
        ) ELSE (
            ECHO !TEST:%_split%=! >> !OF!
            SET OF=!_outfile2!
            ECHO. >> !OF!
        )
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO %%A >> !OF!
    )
)
```

Comment: 1) This will not work properly if the delimiter appears in the middle of a line. 2) This will strip leading spaces and tabs from each line. 3) This will strip out empty lines. 4) This will strip out lines that begin with `;`.

Comment: Also, the search and replace is not case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

So many people want to use pure batch to manipulate text files, and it is incredibly difficult to achieve a robust solution. It can usually be done, but the end result is likely to be painfully slow when dealing with large files, and it requires arcane, and often-times undocumented constructs.

There are many tools from the unix world that have been ported to windows that could be used to solve this problem, such as sed and awk. Most popular text processing utilities use regular expressions.

I recommend you use [JREPL.BAT - a hybrid JScript/batch regular expression text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044). JREPL.BAT is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward, and it is nearly as fast as a compiled text utility. Full documentation is embedded within the script.

A simple command line one-liner is all that is required to solve this particular problem:

```
jrepl "([\s\S]*?)Charlie([\s\S]*)" "stdout.Write($2);$1" /m /j /f input.txt /o output1.txt >output2.txt
```

You should use CALL JREPL if you use the command within a batch script.

**How it works**

A single JREPL call can conveniently write to both stdout and a file.

- `/f input.txt` specifies the input file
- `/o output1.txt` specifies that normal output should be written to the first output file
- `>output2.txt` redirects stdout to the second output file
- `/j` treats the replacement string as a JScript expression
- `/m` (multi-line mode) treats the entire input file as a single string, allowing searches across multiple lines.
- The first argument is the search string
- The second argument is the replacement string (a compound JScript expression). The first expression writes the 2nd captured string to stdout. The second (last) expression is the first captured string, and it is what replaces the search string and gets written to the normal output (in this case the first output file).

If you don't yet understand regular expressions, I highly recommend taking the time to study them. There are many tutorials available on the web, and they are incredibly powerful. I also recommend studying the JREPL documentation, and reading the entire JREPL DosTips post.